# MySQL. Average price, connecting two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am learning MySQL and I currently do not understand how to do something.
I have two tables and I want to display some stuff out of it, it's pretty hard to explain so I'd rather show you.
These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proprietate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serie_buletin` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `cnp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nr_vehicul` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_cumpararii` date NOT NULL,
  `pret` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_persoana` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicul` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nr_vehicul` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `id_marca` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `culoare` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `capacitate_cilindrica` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_proprietate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_proprietate) REFERENCES proprietate(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

And these are my values inside my tables:

```
INSERT INTO `proprietate` (`id`, `serie_buletin`, `cnp`, `nr_vehicul`, `data_cumpararii`, `pret`, `id_persoana`) VALUES
(1, 'AK162332', 2006036035087, 4, '2014-05-01', 35000, 1),
(2, 'AK162332', 2006036035087, 10, '2014-05-02', 90000, 2),
(3, 'AK176233', 6548751520125, 2, '2014-05-03', 55000, 3),
(4, 'BZ257743', 6548751520125, 2, '2014-05-04', 25000, 4),
(5, 'BZ257743', 2006036035087, 15, '2014-05-05', 63000, 5),
(6, 'DC456542', 2003564784513, 7, '2014-05-06', 30000, 6),
(7, 'EN654872', 2012654879521, 6, '2014-05-07', 50000, 7);

INSERT INTO `vehicul` (`id`, `nr_vehicul`, `marca`, `id_marca`, `tip`, `culoare`, `capacitate_cilindrica`, `id_proprietate`) VALUES
(1, 4, 'Mercedes', 1, 'CLK 350', 'negru', 3500, 1),
(2, 10, 'Mercedes', 1, 'S 500', 'silver', 5000, 2),
(3, 2, 'Mercedes', 1, 'ML 550', 'alb', 5500, 3),
(4, 2, 'BMW', 2, '325', 'galben', 2500, 4),
(5, 15, 'BMW', 2, 'X5', 'negru', 3500, 5),
(6, 7, 'Audi', 3, 'R5', 'mov', 5000, 6),
(7, 6, 'Audi', 3, 'Q5', 'metalic', 3000, 7);
```

What I want to display is:

```
 marca    |  nr_vehicul   |  average_price
  Audi    |      13       |     40000
  BMW     |      17       |     44000
Mercedes  |      16       |     60000
```

How can I do that? So far I have managed to display the first two columns but I have no idea how to reference the first table in the second and calculate the average price.
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT marca, SUM(nr_vehicul) AS nr_vehicul FROM vehicul GROUP BY marca
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Mihai: I'll go over what you gave me, thank you. Hopefully I'll understand.

Comment: @Strawberry: If you're going to post useless comments and not even try to help me, don't post at all. Please. Yes, I did post a similar thing but I want to fully understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Dont worry,we were all beginners.I could give you the solution but it`s better for you if you take the time to understand JOINs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should join your tables to get combined information from both of them:

```
SELECT marca, SUM(vehicul.nr_vehicul) AS nr_vehicul, avg(pret) as pret
FROM vehicul 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN proprietate on (id_proprietate = proprietate.id)
GROUP BY marca;
```

see [this sql fiddle session](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4803/6) for the output.

First you select the data (column names with appropriate functions used) you need: `marca, SUM(vehicul.nr_vehicul), AVG(pret)`, then you construct the joined structure from where mysql should retrieve these informations: `vehicul`, `proprietate`.

For this structure you need primarily the `vehicul` table, by which you will group the result set. You want to join the proprietate table to the vehicul table properly, to make sure the correct data structure is created. Since you have foreign key from one table to the other, the easiest way to do it is to use that key: `LEFT OUTER JOIN proprietate on (id_proprietate = proprietate.id)`.

For more information on understanding the different JOIN types, [please see this article by  Craig Buckler](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Comment: This is what I am looking for but I don't want to just copy and paste the answer. I want to make sure I understand what you've done.
Basically you've selected the column 'marca', you made the SUM of the column 'nr_vehicul' from the table 'vehicul' and you calculated the average price of 'pret' after you joined the table 'proprietate' to the first table and you made the connection between the PK in 'proprietate' with the FK in 'vehicul'?

Comment: @MrSilent, yes, that's it. Please see my update for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT type, AVG(pret) FROM vehicul GROUP BY marca";  
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "The average price of ". $row['type']. " is $".$row['AVG(price)'];}</code>
```

should return the average price per marca